# iOS: Does an in-memory cache with TTL and max size exist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, caching

I am in need of an in-memory general-purpose cache for my iOS app that supports giving items inside a time-to-live and auto-clearing elements when a max size is reached. Does such a thing exist?

NSCache won't work because it doesn't support TTL.

I'm in the process of rolling my own, but it'd be nice if I didn't have to.

Comment: I say - roll your own. TTL is not that hard to implement.

Comment: I'd like a few more nice things like persistence and such. You're right though, none of this is particularly difficult to implement. I'd just like to avoid spending too much time implementing it all if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NSCache` you can utilize the `setTotalCostLimit:` to purge memory after a certain Limit.  As the Docs state.

> The default value is 0, which means there is no limit on the size of the cache. If you add an object to the cache, you may pass in a specified cost for the object, such as the size in bytes of the object. If adding this object to the cache causes the cache’s total cost to rise above totalCostLimit, the cache could automatically evict some of its objects until its total cost falls below totalCostLimit. The order in which the cache evicts objects is not guaranteed. This limit is not a strict limit, and if the cache goes over the limit, an object in the cache could be evicted instantly, at a later point in time, or possibly never, all depending on the implementation details of the cache.

If you haven't already, You should check out the [Caching and Purgeable Memory](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/CachingPurgeableMemory/Introduction/Introduction.html) documentation.

Alternatively I've run across an `NSCache` class written in C++ with TTL Support. You can very well use this as a guide while writing your own, can check it out [here](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/tamu-cs-691-dns-resolver/trunk/DNSv2/NSCache.cpp)

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you! From the responses here and a few other SA questions I've seen, consensus points to rolling my own. (I feel like this is a common problem, what's with there not being a pre-built solution?). If nobody shows up with a better answer, I will accept your response.